# xml parsing using 2 tables

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing, django-views

I written a function to save the data in xml file to database.I am using two models ,see the below.

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)   
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

my .xml file is

```
 <book>
    <book_id>101</book_id>
    <book_name>Python</book_name>
    <publisher_name>Maxwell</publisher_name>
    <author_id>1002</author_id>
    <first_name>John</first_name>
    <last_name>Dezosa</last_name>
    <email>john@gmail.com</email>
    <age>34</age>
  </book>
  <book>
    <book_id>102</book_id>
    <book_name>Django</book_name>
    <publisher_name>Technical</publisher_name>
    <author_id>1003</author_id>
    <first_name>Josep</first_name>
    <last_name>Raj</last_name>
    <email>joseph@gmail.com</email>
    <age>29</age>
  </book>
```

What i required is to save the xml data into appropriate fields.From google i learned about paring using single table,here i don't know how to create the object for the "author" table.

I tried with the below code

```
for books in xmlDocTree.iter('book'):
            book_id = books[0].text
            book_name = books[1].text
            publisher_name = books[2].text
            author_id = books[3].text     
            books.first_name = books[0].text
            books.last_name = books[1].text 
            books.email = books[2].text
            books.age = books[3].text
```

getting the following traceback

```
AttributeError at /addxml/
first_name
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/addxml/
Django Version: 1.3.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
first_name
Exception Location: /root/Samples/DemoApp/DemoApp/views.py in addxml, line 106
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your books model does not have a `first_name`

You need to create an author object, and then save the author as a foreign key to the book model.

```
for books in xmlDocTree.iter('book'):
    book_id = books[0].text
    book_name = books[1].text
    publisher_name = books[2].text

    author_id = books[3].text     
    first_name = books[4].text
    last_name = books[5].text 
    email = books[6].text
    age = books[7].text 

    author, _ = Author.objects.get_or_create(id=author_id, defaults={'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name, 'email': email, 'age': age})
    author.save()

    book, - =  Book.objects.get_or_create(book_id=book_id, defaults={'book_name': book_name, 'published_name': publisher_name, 'author': author)})
    book.save()
```

You might need another column in your `Author` model called `author_id`

Comment: I did the correction as you said,see i am getting this error ParseError at /addxml/
junk after document element: line 13, column 2

Comment: getting the above error in this line                          xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)

Comment: ,your answer is right i did a mistake in xml file i solved. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Hi,just now i noticed that Book model data gets printing in author model ie,for first name the answer is 102 which is the value of book_id,what would be the problem(instead of first name it is printing  book_id value